# Скажите, как правильно просклонять салат латук?

Tags: склонение, существительные

Интересует, как правильно будет: *2 кочана салата латук или 2 кочана салата латука?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, что **2 кочана салата латука**

Почему: потому что название "латук" [склоняется](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUJ4V.png), видовое слово после родового в данном случае тоже склоняется: *"я люблю дерево берёзу"*, а не *"я люблю дерево берёза"*.

Пример из Нацкорпуса (В. П. Катаев "Святой колодец"):

> Мы также ели много полезной зелени – вроде салата латука, артишоков,
> спаржи, пили черный кофе.

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкорпусе часто встречается **дефисное** написание:

Вопрос № 236365
Здравствуйте! Срочный вопрос!
Как правильно писать словосочетание "салат(-)латук" и каким образом его склонять.

*Ответ справочной службы русского языка*

Склоняются обе части: **салат-латук, салата-латука** и т. д.

И «огородная зелень»: салат-латук, мелкий кресс-салат, порей, мята, кориандр [Александр Савинов 2014].